# setImageRessource doesn't work in a timer android studio

Tags: java, android, timer, imageview

I'm a beginner...
Why did my "setImageRessource" doesn't work?
The image "fiole" have to change at 10% and at 20% of the duration of the timer but on my phone, the image never change...

However, the text of the textViex is changed when the time equals the quarter of the duration.

```
public class XActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
int duree;
String duration;
int durationInt;
protected TextView tempsRestant;
protected ImageView fiole;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_X);
    this.duree = 0;
    this.duration = getIntent().getStringExtra("DURATION");
    this.durationInt = Integer.parseInt(duration)*60;
    this.tempsRestant=findViewById(R.id.tempsRestant);
    this.fiole=findViewById(R.id.fiole);


    final Timer modecTimer = new Timer();
    modecTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            duree += 1;
            if (duree==(durationInt/100)*10){
                fiole.setImageResource(R.drawable.fiole10p);
            }
            if (duree==(durationInt/100)*20){
                fiole.setImageResource(R.drawable.fiole20p);
            }
            if (duree==durationInt/4){
                tempsRestant.setText("some text");
            }

            }


        }
    }, 1000, 1000);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setImageResource didn't work, because it needs to be run on UIThread

```
modecTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                duree += 1;
                if (duree==(durationInt/100)*10){
                    fiole.setImageResource(R.drawable.fiole10p);
                }
                if (duree==(durationInt/100)*20){
                    fiole.setImageResource(R.drawable.fiole20p);
                }
                if (duree==durationInt/4){
                    tempsRestant.setText("some text");
                }
            });
        }
}, 1000, 1000);
```

Comment: how can I do what I want to do?  runOnUiThread(new  Runnable() {

                    public void run() {
                        if (duree == (durationInt / 100) * 10) {
                            fiole.setImageResource(R.drawable.fiole10p);
                        } doesn't work